# Increasing Accuracy of text extraction using pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am working on a project to extract text from images for their translation, but the pytessearct library is not able to detect all the words. I need 100 percent accuracy in detection. How to make it more accurate?

Image I am using for extraction:

[image]

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont  # opening and manipulating images
from PIL import ImageEnhance
from pytesseract import Output

custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm %d' % 12
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

im = Image.open("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\photo2.png")
im=im.convert("RGB")
#im.show()
width, height = im.size

curr_con = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
new_con =4.0  
# Contrast enhanced by a factor of 0.3
img_contrasted = curr_con.enhance(new_con)  
# shows updated image in image viewer
#img_contrasted.show()

# Print the dimensions
extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im , lang='eng', config=custom_config)
data = pytesseract.image_to_data(im , output_type=Output.DICT, lang='eng', config=custom_config)
data1 = pytesseract.image_to_data(im , lang='eng', config=custom_config)
#print(extracted_text)
print(data1)
```

This is the code i am using but it is not able to detect all the words.
Example in the above image in line ' direction of twist'  it detects all words except the word 'direction'. I have tried increasing the contrast and all but the doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free browser extension for Firefox and Chrome, called Copyfish. It claims to be open source. But it appears to work using an online API. So, if that's the case, it sends images to the ocrspace server. If that's okay with you, [you can find it on futurepedia.](https://www.futurepedia.io/tool/copyfish) I am only just now trying it out. So don't be mad if it doesn't work for everything. It does recognize all the text in your image. That's all I can say about it right now.

You can also get an API key from ocrspace and write your own OCR app, I suppose. By itself, that won't provide any advantage, but there might be some image processing you could do to improve accuracy. A free utility called `unpaper` can help.

1. Fix the DPI to at least 300.
2. Ensure that text size is appropriate, e.g., 12pt or above.
3. Use deskewing and dewarping techniques to fix text lines.
4. Make sure that the illumination of the image is uniform and bright.
5. denoise the image, which you can achieve with image thresholding.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Keras_OCR pipeline for text detection and extraction and it has a very high accuracy. Anyone facing the same problem as me should try the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).